# how to hide Active Directory objects for all domain users

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2019

All users in the OU "Society\Members" and "Society\Members_ENG" are members of the bullitin group "Domain Users".

How can I set in the Domain Controller's Active Directory so that each user of "Domain users" group cannot see the objects (both computers and users shouldn't be visible) of Active Directory from RSAT? Or alternatively, can I deny that permission for all users of a OU (e.g. Society\Members or Society\Members_ENG?

I'm using Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition

This is what a domain user can see from any workstation (W10 Pro with RSAT component installed)
[image]

I've already tried to edit "Domain users" security options to deny read, but the group becomes an unknown object. The same happens applying the same rule on the OU.
I'm expecting to find a solution applying a group policy or a rule again from Active Directory in the Domain Controller.

Comment: There are two approaches. One, as you mentioned, involves permissioning containers appropriately to deny access, except to the required groups. The second requires enabling List Object Mode dsHeuristics.  Both are extensively documented.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29558.active-directory-controlling-object-visibility-list-object-mode.aspx  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28241.controlling-object-visibility-deny-list-content.aspx

Comment: @GregAskew I fixed following this link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28241.controlling-object-visibility-deny-list-content.aspx and using the "Denying List Contents – Intraforest Test Case 1".

Comment: I'm asking my self why this question is down voted? It is a legit question IMHO. Security by Obscurity may not work at all, but it could also be required by law or internal requirements for legit reasons

Comment: @djdomi yes, indeed! We have a domain in a private cloud enviroment and users don't belong to the same organization, so we've to protect their privacy due to privacy laws and GDPR rules.